# Legacy Problems trying FeatureTools exercises

Tags: python, numpy, featuretools

I was trying this exercise in GitHub:
https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/automated-feature-engineering/blob/master/walk_through/Automated_Feature_Engineering.ipynb

but the code is too old to run on the newest version.

The first problem was entity_from_dataframe() function.
It was deprecated, so I changed it into add_relationship() function.

After this, I encountered another problem on this code:
r_client_previous = ft.Relationship(es['clients']['client_id'],
es['loans']['client_id'])

The newest FeatureTools requires more parameters 'parent_column_name', 'child_dataframe_name', and 'child_column_name', but I don't know what should I enter in that parameters. Could you help me?

Also, is there another legacy code in that GitHub page that should be revised?
Thanks.

line 43, in 
r_client_previous = ft.Relationship(es['clients']['client_id'],
TypeError: **init**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'parent_column_name', 'child_dataframe_name', and 'child_column_name'

Answer (score 1):

That notebook was created prior to the release of Featuretools 1.0, which changed the EntitySet api to use Woodwork data types. Please see the Featuretools guide on [Transitioning to Featuretools 1.0](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/resources/transition_to_ft_v1.0.html) for guidance on how to update the notebook to work with the latest Featuretools.

There are lots of smaller changes that you can read about in the above guide, but the main one will be changing usage of `EntitySet.entity_from_dataframe` to `EntitySet.add_dataframe` and updating the calls to add relationships (see the Defining-and-adding-relationships section of the guide).